# Key combo to Abort accidental massive paste-into-terminal mistake

Tags: terminal, keyboard-shortcuts

Due to the vagaries of virtualbox's clipboard I ended up pasting a huge logfile into the terminal instead of a small snippet of text.

At this point, as the log file contains many newlines etc. it goes absolutely mad trying to execute each line as a command... as you may imagine this is both undesirable and can take some time.

Ctrl+C doesn't work here as it just moves on to the next line of the pasted file - so what (if anything) is the magic Vulcan nerve pinch required to stop the terminal completely?

Comment: Search for `bracketed paste`. I use `zsh`, which includes it by default, but I *think* it's now in [bash](https://cirw.in/blog/bracketed-paste)?

Comment: @Sparhawk Yes it is also available since bash-4.4 / readline-7.0.

Comment: As for the original question: Holding down Ctrl+C often helps me in this case. Other than that, you can close the terminal emulator window or tab.