# Global filter on clipboard?

Tags: filter, xclip

I'd like to make kind of filter for clipboard to remove newline characters at the end from anything I copy-paste on a daily basis. I know I could set a daemon listening through `xclip` for changes and remove it but I am a little afraid in terms of efficiency of very frequent tests for changes if I don't copy-paste that often in fact... Would it be possible to make a filter only on paste so that every text with trailing new line would be modified right before paste?

Obviously I am afraid mostly of pasting commands into terminal (no matter if I use `ctrl+v`, `shift+insert` or middle mouse button) but I can easily live with pressing enter one more time in any case...

Comment: Possibly related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364632/key-combo-to-abort-accidental-massive-paste-into-terminal-mistake

Comment: How running multiple commands is related with stripping new line character from the end only? In fact, I don't mind running multiple commands by pasting them together as I would need to select many lines first - way harder to miss that fact than a single `\n` at the end...

Comment: You wrote "I am afraid mostly of pasting commands into terminal".  The linked question addresses that.  The comments then suggest [bracketed paste](https://cirw.in/blog/bracketed-paste), a feature of many shells and terminals to translate those newlines into a different character.